# Proving that the operator $T_\ell : X \to X$ defined by $T_\ell x=\ell(x)z$ on a Banach space $X$ for any $\ell \in X'$ and $z \in X$

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

Q. Let $z$ be a fixed vector in a Banach space $X$, then prove that the operator $T_\ell : X \to X$ defined by $$T_\ell x=\ell(x)z,~x \in X,$$
for any $\ell \in X',$ the dual space, is compact.

Can we make $T_\ell$ as a norm limit of a sequence of compact linear operators on $X$? How to utilize the continuity of $\ell$?

Comment: Any  finite rank operator is compact. $T$ has rank $1$.

Comment: Continuity of $l$ is equivalent to its boundedness.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Denote the closed unit ball of $X$ by $B$. You need to show that
$\overline{T_{l}(B)}$ is compact. Let $x\in B$, then
\begin{eqnarray*}
||T_{l}(x)|| & = & ||l(x)z||\\
 & = & |l(x)|\cdot||z||\\
 & \leq & ||l||\cdot||x||\cdot||z||\\
 & \leq & ||l||\cdot||z||.
\end{eqnarray*}
Also note that $T_{l}(x)$ takes the form $kz$ for some scalar $k$,
so $T_{l}(B)\subseteq\{\alpha z\mid|a|\leq||l|| \}$. Observe
that the RHS is compact with respect to the norm topology, so $\overline{T_{l}(B)}$
is compact. That is, $T_{l}$ is a compact operator.

Comment: Typo fixed.....